# How can I put my signature on the right side of the document using latex? **Latex**

Tags: format, latex

I am creating my cv using latex template. I want to keep all the information under 2 pages but signature is coming on the third page. I wonder if I could use extra space on the second page to put my signature. I am sharing the screenshot of the document and also the code.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{ecv}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={190mm,280mm},
  left=12mm,
  right=12mm,
  top=12mm,
  bottom=12mm,
 }
\makeatletter
% Command to layout the portrait (must be 60mmx40mm) 
\renewcommand\ecv@Portrait[1]{%
  %% A frame as placeholder (with  some 1mm inner padding):
 % \pgfrect[stroke]{\pgfxy(6.80,0.65)}{\pgfxy(4.3,-5.3)}
  %% Actually a concrete digital image:
  \pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=40mm,width=35mm]{portrait}{#1}
  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(8.77,0.10)}{\pgfbox[left,top]{\pgfuseimage{portrait}}}
}
\makeatother
%\ecvPortrait{cropped.jpeg}
%\flushright\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{cropped.jpeg}\\[\baselineskip] % Your photo
%\flushright{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{cropped.jpeg}}\\
\ecvName{Doe John}

\renewcommand{\ecvJobs}{Summary}
\renewcommand{\ecvResearch}{Personal Projects}
\renewcommand{\ecvProfession}{Work Experience}
\renewcommand{\ecvPublications}{Certifications}

\begin{document}

\begin{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Person
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPerson}{\ecvPerson}}

\ecvEPR{Name}{\textsc{John} Doe}
\ecvEPR{Address}{texa, US}
\ecvEPR{Telephone}{(9}
%\ecvEPR{Fax}{<Area code>--<Faxnumber>}
\ecvEPR{E-Mail} {\ecvHyperEMail{a28rma@gmail.com}}
\ecvEPR{Linkedin} {\ecvHyperEMail{https://www.linkedin.com/in/johnDoe8/}}
\ecvEPR{Nationality}{Indianan}
\ecvEPR{Date of birth}{24, Indiana}

\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvJobs}{\ecvJobs}}
\vspace*{-4cm}
%\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAwards}{\ecvAwards}}
\ecvEFR{\small\emph{Microsoft Azure Cloud Fundamentals AZ 900 certified}}%{\begin{description} 
{\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\diamond$}
\begin{itemize}\vspace*{-2cm}\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}
\justifying\small \item Highly-skilled professional, offering 6+ years of consulting experience in all aspects of data analytics, including mining, generation, and visualization; familiar with Agile methodologies
\item Technical writing experience in relevant areas, including queries, reports and presentations; strong R, Python, Advanced Excel and QlikView skills with the ability to learn other analytical skills and tools
\item Exposure in applying business and functional knowledge including testing standards, guidelines, and testing methodology to meet the team's overall test objectives
\end{itemize}}\vspace*{-2cm}
\vspace*{-2cm}
%\end{description}}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Profession
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvProfession}{\ecvProfession}\vspace*{-2cm}}
% Chronologisch beginnend mit den juengsten Beschaeftigungen
\ecvEFR{March 2018 - Present\\\vspace*{1cm}
{Core Competencies:}
{\small
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\textit{\begin{itemize}
\item Data Quality Assessment
\item Data Visualization 
\item Master Data Management
\item Data Mining  
\item Business Intelligence
\item MI Reporting
\item Root Cause Analysis
\item Troubleshooting
\item Team Management  
\item Stakeholder Management  
\item Cloud Computing
\item Agile Methodology
\end{itemize}}}}
{\textbf{texa, US}\newline
\textbf{Role: Data Analyst / Consultant} \newline
\textbf{Main Responsibilities:}{\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}
\small\justifying{
\item Working closely with project managers to understand and maintain focus on their analytical needs, including identifying critical metrics and KPIs, and deliver actionable insights to relevant decision-makers
\item Proactively analyzing data to answer key questions from stakeholders or out of self-initiated curiosity with an eye for what drives business performance, investigating and communicating areas for improvement in efficiency and productivity
\item Creating and maintaining rich interactive visualizations through data interpretation and analysis integrating various reporting components from multiple data sources
\item Proficiently developed visually impactful dashboards in Excel and Tableau for data reporting by using pivot tables and power pivots
\item  Collating data  in  an  easy  to  interpret  format  and  collaborating with business stakeholders   to   discuss   data   metrics and   present recommendations
\item  Helping in developing a data migration strategy and data dictionary
\item Preparing excel templates using VBA to support banking client requirements for tracking the progress of Non-Performing loans (retail and non-retail banking)
\item Using G-suite functionalities to create google sites for internal use.
\item Helping in setting up and automating a business solution for the internal teams to extract insights from external clients data.}
\end{itemize}}}
\ecvENR{Software tools}{\small SQL Server, Teradata, Alteryx, Microsoft Azure, Tableau, QlikView, Visio, Python, R Studio, Microsoft Suite, G-Suite, Advanced Excel and VBA}

\ecvEFR{Mar 2013 - Dec 2016\\\vspace*{.5cm}
\textbf{Growth Path:}
\textit{{\item Test Engineering Senior Analyst}\\ { (Nov 2016 - Dec 2016)}}\\
\textit{{\item Test Engineering Analyst}\\ { (Sept 2014 - Oct 2016)}}\\
\textit{{\item Test Engineering Associate}\\ { (Mar 2013 - Aug 2014)}\\}}{{{\textbf{ Indiana Pvt Limited}}\\
\textbf{Main Responsibilities:}\\
{\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}
\small\justifying{
\item Assembled various reports like KPI  reports,  Daily  Status  Report, Billing Reports, Residual Risk Report, Traceability matrix, etc. using excel and AIT 
\item Worked in close collaboration with Clients, Stakeholders and Release Managers for the successful execution of the demand within the timeline
\item Performed test coverage analysis, risk analysis, RCA analysis, risk prioritization, and analysis of defect trends     
\item Carried out testing of data quality and flagging process improvements for improving data quality      
\item Responsible for quality assurance of data harvested from online stores by using SQL to identify significant changes in the daily data
\item Involved and researched in data mapping and loading to in-house Data Quality Engine using Talend
\item Worked in close collaboration with Automation Developers to create regression test scripts via automation tools such as Selenium Web driver, QTP, Load Runner, and TOSCA
%\item Involved in setting-up test bed      
\item Carried out Smoke, System and Regression Manual Testing  to  all  QA applications and UAT environments
%\item Checked the status of every issue across each module day today and update the team lead on a daily
%\item Performed the Functional, Integration, Database and Regression Testing
\item Worked in close collaboration with the developers to ensure that they have understood the issues and proactively involved in Defect review meeting}
\end{itemize}}}}
\ecvENR{Software tools}{\small Oracle database, HP ALM,HP QTP, SOAP UI, TOSCA, Talend, Excel, Notepad++}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Education
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace*{-2cm}\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvEducation}{\ecvEducation}}

% Universit"at
\ecvEFR{Period}{2017-2018}
\ecvENR{Acquired qualifications}
                {\ecvBold{Masters In Data Analytics}}
\ecvENR{Institute}
                {NC US}
%\ecvENR{Principal subjects}
              %  {<List of the major subjects>}
%\ecvENR{Minor subjects}
                %{<List of minor subjects>}
%\ecvENR{Grade}   {Avarage grade <overall avarage grade>}
% Schule
\ecvEFR{Period}{2009-2013}
\ecvENR{Acquired qualifications}
                {\ecvBold{Bachelors in Technology\\ (Electronics and Communication Engineering)}}
\ecvENR{Institute}
                {NCSU, Indiana}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Research
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvResearch}{\ecvResearch}}
\ecvEFB{Sales Dashboard (QlikView)}{\begin{itemize}\vspace*{-2cm}\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}
\small\item Extracted, transformed, and loaded the data from CSV files and webpage to produce a sales dashboard
\item Managed the KPIs (Customer, Transaction, Sales), Pivot Table, Heat map based on sales band, and Sales by Salesperson and wide variety of new sheet objects (list box and multi-box) to browse the data
\item Developed a dashboard that covers all the important measures of the business, resulting in helping the business stakeholders in decision making 
\end{itemize}
}
\ecvEFB{Machine Learning Using Python}{
\begin{itemize}\vspace*{-1cm}\setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}\small
\item Used Decision Tree Classifier for predicting the music genre based on age and gender.Used The library - Pandas, Scikit-Learn, Numpy and Matplolib
\item Bagged the accuracy score of 84per when 70per of the train and 30per test data was used
\end{itemize}}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Publications
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPublications}{\ecvPublications}}
         %\vspace*{-1.85cm}    
%\ecvEFR{1.}{\emph{Microsoft Azure Cloud Fundamentals AZ 900 certified}}
                    % <Name of the journal>. <Publisher>, 
                     %<City>, <Year>}



%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Jobs
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvJobs}{\ecvJobs}}

%\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
%\ecvENR{Employer}
              %   {\ecvBold{<Name of the Company>}, <City>/<Country>}
%\ecvENR{Employment}
               %  {<Type of the employment>}
%\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
              %%   {<List of activities>
               %  }
\vspace*{-2cm}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Languages
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvLanguages}{\ecvLanguages}}

\ecvERSub{English \textbf{\small Proficient}}\\\vspace{-.5cm} 
\ecvERSub{Hindi \textbf{\small Native}}\\\vspace{-.1cm}
\ecvERSub{Deutsch \textbf{\small Self-Learning}}\\\vspace{-.1cm}
%{\ecvBold{Self-Learning}}
%\ecvEBSub{Other languages}
 %                       {<Language> -- Read: <Degree>, Write: 
  %                       <Degree>, Talk: <Degree>}
%{\ecvBold{Native}}
%{\ecvBold{Proficient}}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Language Travels
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ecvBSub{\ecvLanguageTravels}

%\ecvEFR{Period}{<Date>--<Date>}
%\ecvENR{Place} {<City>/<Country>}
%\ecvENR{Vendor}
%                {<Organizer>}
%\ecvENR{Certificate}
%                {<Name of the acquired certificate>}


%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\ecvPageBreak
%%\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAbilities}{\ecvAbilities}}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / social
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\ecvEBSub{Social Skills}
   %             {<Description of the social strengths>
    %            }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / organisational
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\ecvEBSub{Organisational Skills}
  %              {<Description of organisational skills>
     %           }
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Abilities / professional
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\ecvBEBSub{Technical Skills}
 %               {<Description of technical skills>}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Hobbies
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ecvBEBSub{Hobbies}
 %               {<List of major hobbies and private interests>
  %              }

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Attachments
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvAttachements}{\ecvAttachements}}

%%               } 

\end{ecv}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Signature
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSig{john Doe}{texa}
\vspace*{-1.85cm}
%\flushleft\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{sign.PNG}\\[\baselineskip] % Your photo
%\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{sign.PNG}\\[\baselineskip] % Your photo
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it does not work in overleaf: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUi0x.png

Comment: I am not able to solve the error within the problem.

Comment: Try to make a [mre] and ask a question about the error. But as long as there are errors and the file you get might or might not be a valid pdf, there is absolutely no point in making cosmetic adjustments about the layout. They might very well be useless once the errors are resolved.